# Android SQLite insert unique

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Simple enough question, but I cant find ant half-decent documentation on it. Right so I've created my SQLite db but it has two problems or one depending how you look at it! The db creates fine and I can show the data in a basic listview, however on changing the orientation of the phone/emulator the insert statements run again and duplicate all the records. Im guessing this has something to do with all the code being placed within the OnCreate() method. 
My main question however is how to do INSERT UNIQUE or query the db to see if the record exists? I just could find any good documentation on SQLite DB parameters on the Android platform.

Any help is much obliged !

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make use of the [DatabaseUtils](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html).stringForQuery() static method that is already in Android SDK to easily retrieve a value, this example is for `String` bot there is also method for `Long`

```
stringForQuery(SQLiteDatabase db, String query, String[] selectionArgs)
```

Utility method to run the query on the db and return the value in the first column of the first row.

Something like

```
String myString=DatabaseUtils.stringForQuery(getDB(),query,selectionArgs);
```

This example was to get a string value, but you can easily adapt to get a `Long` value, and your query should be something like

```
select count(*) from mytable where field1='stringtocheckagainst'
```

if this returns a number greater the zero, then the field already exists in the database.

**Also look into code for handling orientation changes.**

---

**UPDATE** by @nutone:

On API 11 and higher, you can also use the `DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries` functions to get the number of (filtered) rows directly.

```
long count = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(getDB(), table, query, selectionArgs);
```

Answer (score 6):

SQLite has an `INSERT OR REPLACE` command (`REPLACE` for short, or use `SQLiteDatabase.replace()`) that can do what you want.

However I'd suggest that your application shouldn't be re-inserting into the database every time your Activity is created unless it really needs to, so you might want to look into changing the design.

Answer (score 2):

One thing is you need to handle your orientation change issue, to access the database on every orientation change consumes a lot.

Second thing, regarding the check duplicate record problem, you can define the column as unique like

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(column_definition, unique(column_names) ON CONFLICT replace);` hen
```

You can perform insert as usual, the db would ensure no duplicates exist.

Comment: This is the best answer. Uniqueness should really be handled at the schema level, not at runtime with extraneous queries. That just adds even more overhead.